# Force sheet fed printer to continuous roll printing

Tags: c#, printing

I have an HP 7760 photo printer. On the printer settings panel there's no roll printing supported. I would like to print via my C# application the same A4 sheet for several times to A4 wide continuous roll paper, but after the first page printed a paper jam occurs. Maybe because the printer expects A4 size paper.
Is there any solution in C# for this problem or it depends on the printer driver? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You can use the [PrinterSettings.PaperSizes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.papersizes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to return all the sizes supported by your printer. You can then change the size.

Comment: So, if I would like to print 100 sheets of A4 page to roll, what would be the papersize? 210 x  29700 mm?